# Oracle SQL left outer join on two subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, join, left-join

I'm working in an oracle database and receive the following error:

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server : Invalid object name

I've also tried joining in the where clause, but I also receive

Here's the query:

```
select UE_invoice.InvoiceNo,
       UE_invoice.DueDate,
       UE_payment.CheckNo,
       UE_payment.Amount

from

(select tblTransaction.InvoiceNo,
       tblTransaction.DueDate
  from tblTransaction,
       tblTransactionType
 where
 tblTransaction.Type = tblTransactionType.TransactionType
 and
 tblTransaction.Date >= '01/01/2018'
 and
 tblTransaction.Type = -88) UE_invoice,

(select tblTransaction.InvoiceNo,
       tblTransaction.DueDate,
       tblTransaction.CheckNo,
       tblTransaction.Amount
from tblTransaction,
     tblTransactionType
 where
 tblTransaction.Type = tblTransactionType.TransactionType
 and
 tblTransaction.Date >= '01/01/2018'
 and
 tblTransaction.Type = -86) UE_payment

Left outer join UE_invoice on UE_invoice.InvoiceNo = UE_payment.InvoiceNo
```

Comment: `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server` Looks like you are using wrong provider for an Oralce DB

Comment: There is a syntax error: `Left outer join` must be written between the tables to be joined. So change the statement into `... (select ... ) UE_payment left outer join  ( select ... ) UE_invoice on ...`. The error message is quite dubious and suggests some other issues.

Comment: By the way, if `tblTransaction.Date` is defined as a `DATE`, you should compare it with a date expression e.g. `tblTransaction.Date >= date '2018-01-01'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the syntax of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` that uses "Table Expressions". Try:

```
select UE_invoice.InvoiceNo,
       UE_invoice.DueDate,
       UE_payment.CheckNo,
       UE_payment.Amount
from (
  select tblTransaction.InvoiceNo,
       tblTransaction.DueDate,
       tblTransaction.CheckNo,
       tblTransaction.Amount
  from tblTransaction,
       tblTransactionType
  where
       tblTransaction.Type = tblTransactionType.TransactionType
    and
      tblTransaction.Date >= '01/01/2018'
    and
    tblTransaction.Type = -86
  ) UE_payment
Left outer join (
  select tblTransaction.InvoiceNo,
       tblTransaction.DueDate
  from tblTransaction,
       tblTransactionType
  where
       tblTransaction.Type = tblTransactionType.TransactionType
    and
       tblTransaction.Date >= '01/01/2018'
    and
    tblTransaction.Type = -88
  ) UE_invoice on UE_invoice.InvoiceNo = UE_payment.InvoiceNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
Left outer join UE_invoice on UE_invoice.InvoiceNo = UE_payment.InvoiceNo
```

with

```
where UE_invoice.InvoiceNo = UE_payment.InvoiceNo
```

Comment: That does work, but it only captures a natural join. I need to see all the invoices, whether or not they have a payment.

Comment: will work if the where condition: where UE_invoice.InvoiceNo = UE_payment.InvoiceNo (+)    -- using old style join

Comment: Ohh... I remember the old style outer joins :D That (+) sign was awesome, and not too many people knew how to use it back in the early 90s!